# Docusign to Salesforce Encryption

Tags: encryption, salesforce, docusignapi

Good evening,
    I have a client who needs a secure portal for a customer to submit sensitive info (SSN, W9's,etc.) that will integrate with Salesforce. Docusign seems perfect for this but we want to ensure the encryption during transmission of information meets SOX requirements. Can anybody confirm the type of encryption that docusign uses both in storage and in transmission of data? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DocuSign is used by customers for SOX-compliant workflows/use cases. Consult your DocuSign account exec or SE for more information for your compliance/audit team.